# Referencing relative cells

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I’ve two columns: when each person starts a new project (D), and when they end (E).

To the right each cell represents each week of the year. The first week is column I.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7vUm.jpg

I want to show the cell as red if they are staffed during that time, and white if they are not. Right now I have three conditional formulas:

```
=I4>D4 make color white
=I4=D4 make color red
=I4<D4 make color red
```

It’s working fine for the first week (I5), but whenever I try to copy it to other rows or columns it is still referencing the same cells (whether I use `$` or not).

Answer (score 0):

Select from I5 to wherever required and apply this CF rule with red fill:

```
=and(I$4>=$D5,I$4<=$E5)
```

Does not handle part weeks elegantly.

Comment: Works! Thanks pnuts!